# vCenter Server: This host currently has no management network redundancy

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

### Background

I'm on a new VMWare install consisting of:

- 1 vCenter Server (containing inventory service, SSO, vCenter server, and web client server)
- 2 ESX Servers configured in a HA group

### Problem

When a I view the summary for any one of my servers, I receive a notice: "This host currently has no management network redundancy".

This is expected in our scenario and we're okay with it.

### Attempted Solutions

As I understand from [this article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004700) and [this discussion](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/225446), the proper way to remove the error message is to ignore it via setting the "das.ignoreRedundantNetWarning" propery to "true".

I took the following steps:

- Logged into vCenter
- Right-clicked on my HA cluster and chose "Edit Settings..."
- Clicked "vSphere HA" section
- Clicked "Advanced Options..."
- Added the "das.ignoreRedundantNetWarning" option with a value of "true".

### Question

How do I get this error to go away, and are there any reasons why adding this option may *not* have worked?

### References

- [Network redundancy message when configuring VMware High Availability in vCenter Server](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004700) [[VMWare KnowledgeBase]](http://kb.vmware.com)
- [How remove a notice " has no management network redundant"](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/225446) [[VMWare Community]](http://communities.vmware.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! One additional step is necessary -- the servers must be reconfigured for HA to remove the error message.

To do this, for each serer:

- In vSphere Client, click on the server
- Click the Summary tab
- In the "Commands" section, click "Reconfigure for vSphere HA".

After this, the error disappears.

**Newbie Note:** I wasn't aware of this because initially, after updating any setting within the HA cluster, VMWare showed task, "Reconfigure Cluster", as complete. I mistook this message at first glance to mean that I didn't need to manually reconfigure the host.

Comment: Correct. Changes arnt commited until you use the Re-configure options.